# iPhone app description in another language without localization?

Tags: iphone, localization

We're looking to submit an app to the iPhone app store in several countries.  The app itself is in English (and we won't have localization for other languages at launch) but we still want to provide app descriptions in several languages.

Does anybody know if this is possible/advisable?

Answer (score 3):

You, you can do this directly in iTunes Connect. Under the "Manage Your Apps" area you can click on the App's Details which will take you to the details area where you can manage your localizations.
Just note that you will have to do this before the app version has been approved by Apple.

Comment: I'm sorry, to clarify, my question was whether or not it was possible to provide a description in another language WITHOUT localizing the app for that language.